# Как в Yii2 переключаться между dev/prod-версиями?

Tags: yii2

В Yii2 Advanced в самом начале когда делаем init он просит указать это dev или prod-версия. Вопрос: как и где это можно потом поменять если потребуется?

Если я не держу проект на локалке, но у меня 2 сервера dev и prod какой конфиг надо в исключения в .git добавить, что бы они не перезатирались постоянно?

Answer (score 0):

В .gitignor не надо ничего добавлять. Достаточно при деплое выполнять команду `./init --env=Production --overwrite=y` на продакшен сервере. Рано или поздно вы будете менять конфиг, что-то добавлять, что-то убирать. А каждый раз менять ручками конфиг на сервере это накладно и не правильно. Что касается секретный данных, типа паролей и ключей, то их можно хранить в переменных окружения и использовать в конфигах продакшен сервера. Так же скорей всего поведение некоторых компонентов будет различаться на проде и девелопе.

Comment: Благодарю вас! Можно уточнить, это какой способ деплоя подразумевается в вашем ответе?

Comment: Способов множество начиная от простого bash скрипта, заканчивая всякими оркестратарами. К примеру http://capistranorb.com/